# android google maps custom tiles change map bearing automatically in offline

Tags: android, google-maps

I have custom tiles that i am using in offline mode in google maps

I want to change the map bearing automatically - meaning the maps will spin according to the compass.

Tried to change the CameraPosition using CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition but the result is not smooth..

How do i cause google maps to do it automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map.animateCamera()` instead of `map.moveCamera()`